# Constructing document yields semi-empty result

Tags: express, mongoose

After executing Customer.create({customerName: 'John'}), the following document is created without error and without the 'customerName' node.

Can anyone tell me why this seemingly simple document creation call yields a semi-blank document? The document in the response from Mongoose is the same as it is in the database itself.

I can't tell if I'm using Mongoose incorrectly or Express incorrectly. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
{ __v: 0, _id: 5452dc48d687bad849d70816 }
```

---

**routes/customer.js**

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Customer = mongoose.model( 'Customer');

exports.create = function(req, res) {
    Customer.create({
        customerName: 'John'
    }, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) return err;
        console.log('Customer created', customer);
        res.send(customer);
    });
}
```

**schema/customer.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customerName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
```

**db.js**

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/CustomerDatabase';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

var customerSchema = require( '../schema/customer.js' );
var Customer = mongoose.model( 'Customer', customerSchema);
```

**routes.js**

```
function SetupRoutes(app, PATH) {
    var db = require('../model/db.js')
    var customer = require( '../routes/customer.js' );
    app.post('/Customer', customer.create);
}

module.exports.SetupRoutes = SetupRoutes;
```

Comment: What's the value of `customerSchema` in db.js?

Comment: The value is an empty object. Good catch! Maybe I need to export schema/customer.js?

Comment: Thanks for helping out an Express newb :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export `customerSchema` from customer.js so that when db.js requires that file, its value is the exported schema:

```javascript
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customerName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
module.exports = customerSchema;
```

However, the more typical pattern is to create the model in customer.js and then export that:

```javascript
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customerName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema);
```